# How to group by only by one reference in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

I have

```
$qb          = $this->getFindQueryBuilder();
        $entityAlias = $this->getEntityAlias();

    $qb->select([
        $entityAlias,
        'product',
        'category',
        'categories',
        'productCategoriesCategory',
        'productCategoriesProduct',
    ]);

    $qb->leftJoin("{$entityAlias}.product", 'product');
    $qb->leftJoin("{$entityAlias}.category", 'category');
    $qb->leftJoin("product.categories", 'categories');
    $qb->leftJoin("categories.category", 'productCategoriesCategory');
    $qb->leftJoin("categories.product", 'productCategoriesProduct');
```

and

```
$qb->groupBy('product.id');
```

so when I added group by expression it correctly grouping by product.id but mistakenly grouping by productCategoriesProduct.id, as product and productCategoriesProduct is the same entity...
So I need grouping only by product.id but select all productCategoriesProduct inside

Comment: Hello, I can not understand what are you trying to achieve. Can you show a sql equivalent query?

Comment: So the main entity from which I select is CategoryProduct,
it has entityFields product and category...
Product has field categories which is collection of categoryProduct...
So when I select from CategoryProduct and group by CategoryProduct.product.id it also groups by
CategoryProduct.product.categories.product.id but I dont need it

Comment: @manix sql is too long and I think it would not be useful